If $E^*$ is separable and $\{x_k\}\subset E$ is bounded, then it has weak Cauchy subsequence.
Suppose that $E$ is a Banach such that $E^*$ is separable. Show that if $\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq E$ is bounded in $E$ then it has a weak Cauchy subsequence.
We define a Cauchy weak sequence as follows: for any neighborhood $V$ of 0 in the weak topology $\sigma(E,E^*)$, there exists a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $x_n-x_m \in V,\ \forall n,m\geq k$. Note that this is equivalent to saying that for all $l \in E^*$ we have $\{\langle l,x_n\rangle\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is Cauchy.
Thus in trying to prove that exists a subsequence such that for all element in the dual espace, we have $\{\langle l,x_{n_j}\rangle\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy.
Since for all $l \in E^*$ and for all $\varepsilon>0$, exists an element of the dense, such that $\|l-l_k\|_{E^*}<\varepsilon$ and since the sequence its bounded, $\|x_n\|_E \leq M$, we have that
$$\langle l,x_n-x_m\rangle \leq \|l-l_k\|_{E^*}(\|x_n\|_E + \|x_m\|_E) +\langle l_k,x_n-x_m\rangle \leq 2M\varepsilon + \langle l_k,x_n-x_m\rangle $$
So, since this is true for every $\varepsilon>0$, we can choose $\varepsilon = 1/j$ and from there built a subsequence, like this
$$\langle l,x_{n_j}-x_{m_j}\rangle \leq 2M\frac{1}{j}+ \langle l_j,x_{n_j}-x_{m_j}\rangle$$
Then if in some way i can bound the extreme right of the expression, im done. But, im stuck here. I suspect that i need to use the fact that E is complete, then again, i cannot see where.

Ok so you reached the conclusion
$$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists l_k,\exists N,\forall m,n\geq N, \;\;\;\;|\langle l,x_n-x_m\rangle| \leq 2M\varepsilon + |\langle l_k,x_n-x_m\rangle|, $$
which is completely correct. You are left with the term $ \langle l_k,x_n-x_m\rangle$ which is not guaranteed to be smaller than $\epsilon$ independently of $k$. However, we can try to make this true for a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$. Indeed, let $\{l_1,l_2,\ldots\}$ be a dense countable subset of $E^*$. Claim: there is a subsequence $\{x_{n_j}\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\{l_k(x_{n_j})\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$. So given this subsequence and $\epsilon>0$, we can find $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\|l-l_k\|_{E^*}<\frac{\epsilon}{3M}, $$
and then for this $k$, we can find an $N_k$ such that for all $i,j\geq N_k$ we have
$$ |l^k(x_{n_i})-l^k(x_{n_j})|<\epsilon/3.$$
Hence, for $i,j\geq N_k$ we have
$$|\langle l,x_{n_i}-x_{n_j}\rangle|<\frac{2}{3}\epsilon+\frac{1}{3}\epsilon=\epsilon. $$
and $\{l(x_{n_j})\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is thus a Cauchy sequence for every $l\in E^*$.
Sketch for proof of claim: For each $k$, we have $\{l^k(x_n)\}$ is bounded. Therefore $\{l^1(x_n)\}$ has Cauchy subsequence which we call $\{l^1(x_{n_j}^1)\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$. Now $\{l^2(x^1_{n_j})\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is also a bounded sequence, hence it itself has a Cauchy subsequence which we call $\{l^2(x^2_{n_j})\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ and so on ...  Now make an infinite table where rows are indexed by $k$, columns by $j$, and each entry in the table is given by $x_{n_j}^k$ and notice that each for each row $k$ we have $\{x_{n_j}^k\}$ is a subsequence of $\{x^{k-1}_{n_j}\}$. Then use a diagonal argument to get the dersired subsequence.

Thanks UserA. I will keep forever this diagonal argument.

I found another way to solve this.
Since $E^*$ is separable, then $(\overline{B_{E^{**}}},\sigma(E^{**},E^*)|_{\overline{B_{E^{**}}}})$ is a metric compact space. Given that $\{x_k\}$ is bounded, so it is $\{J_{x_k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. Where $J$ is the evaluation map. We can assume that $\{J_{x_k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\overline{B_{E^{**}}}$. Therefore, exists a subsequence $\{x_{k_j}\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$, such that $\{J_{k_j}\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges on $\sigma(E^{**},E^*)|_{\overline{B_{E^{**}}}}$, namely, for all $l\in E^*$ the subsequence $\{\langle l, x_{k_j}\rangle\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$, in particular its Cauchy.

Yes you can also use such arguments though this would invoke the Banach-Alaoglu theorem (and hence the Tychonoff theorem) at some point, which I would consider heavy machinery for such a problem.

Indeed would be a overkill
